# Place dashes in GUIDs using replace all

Tags: notepad++, guid

I've got a file with 200 or so GUID's scattered throughout that have had their dashes removed. I need to put these dashes back in but doing it manually would be tedious and time consuming. Is there a way to do a replace all, perhaps in notepad++, to place dashes in the GUIDS?

Comment: It is easy with a regex replace if you know how the GUIDs look like and where the hyphens belong.

Comment: How do _your_ GUIDs look like?

Comment: The GUIDs are scattered throughout the file contained in single quotes like such: '35B7A5E7A7AF4F38A313D6F7CB219347'
I need to place dashes in all of them like such: '35B7A5E7-A7AF-4F38-A313-D6F7CB219347'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press CTRL+H to open the "Replace"-Dialog:

Enter

```
  ([0-9a-f]{8})([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{12})
```

in the "Find What"-Textfield and

```
$1-$2-$3-$4-$5
```

int the "Replace With"-Textfield. Make sure to have checked the "Regular Expression" checkbox.

Press the "Replace All" button and the magic will happen.

Comment: Why would you use `[0-9a-z]`? GUIDs are most often represented as series of hexadecimal digits, so `[0-9a-f]` should do fine (assuming case-insensitive matching).

Comment: @michael: The question was not clear about the format of the file containing the dashless GUIDS. I updated the answer in order to match 9 characters at the end of the GUID. And yes, a-f should do fine, I will update it in a second :)

Comment: @Simon there are twelve digits in the last block

Comment: This worked perfectly for me (after I got the latest version of notepad++).

Comment: It should be noted that if you are using an earlier version (such as 5.9.6.2 like I was) this particular notation does not work. I had to use `([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F])` as the find and `\1-\2-\3-\4-\5` as the replace.

Answer (score 5):

With notepad++ do following :

At present you should see something like this in notepad++

> ```
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> 1414527670f747218137fd1059046a4e
> ```

Create one column of 200 dashes and copy the column using Alt+ Mouse Selection (vertically).

Now you should be able to paste these 200 dashes wherever you like in above data. I did this in less than a minute for 20 records shown above. You will hardly take 10 mins ?
Much more quicker than a regex ;), specially if you consider the efforts of programming and testing.

See my data for 20 records below :

```
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
14145276-70f7-4721-8137-fd1059046a4e
```

Hope I am clear.
Read [this](http://kudithipudi.org/2008/07/08/howto-select-column-in-notepad/) for column select details in notepad++

Comment: Actually, you don't need to copy/paste anything - simply use the vertical ALT+Mouse and press "-" to insert "-" to all lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess I should specify that the GUIDS are scattered throughout the file, its not just a list of GUIDS.

Comment: Ohh, please update the question so that others are aware of it.

Comment: you added a new comment. The question stays as it is. Please edit the question and add your comments there.

Comment: @N4villu5 all I see is a comment under the question.

Comment: @N4villu5 : My bad. It is fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @JanDvorak : He added the word 'scattered' in his first line of question. :)

Comment: @AYK oh. OCR + NLP cache fail :-)